# TFS fails to merge node modules with shasum check failed

Tags: node.js, tfs, gruntjs, tfsbuild

After noticing a sudden Deploy Failure with log messages like :

```
 npm WARN package.json doc-home@0.1.0 No repository field.
```

I then looked a my merge from DEV to TEST and I see that there are several things missing with using beyond compare.

```
node_modules  (this folder is missing from the merge, but shouldn't it get created automatically?)

test.pubxml.user   is missing

public (folder in which folders and files get copied to)
```

I have never had to open the test branch of the code before, but with a rebuild, that compiles fine, but still missing the folders and files and I typically

```
Right click on Gruntfile.js and select "Task Runner Explorer" of which Failed to load.
```

I really should not have to open up this Test branch etc... I haven't had to in the past.

Update:

Noticing that Express and a few other modules are not on the build server

```
npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for C:\Users\TFSBUILD\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3420-Fr2fVifk\srpdop06\express\-\express-3.20.2.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: c604027746e60f3da0a4b43063375d21c3235858
npm ERR! Actual:   1a86f8d102f05e03020b2749db139f2817be44d1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

It was that an account was shutdown and the npmjs.org registry needs a call to go through validation of the proxy server.

```
config.js needed to be updated for iisnode.
```

Then deleting the cache directory and restart iisnode.